# How to use truffle-plugin-verify when you are not deploying the contract?

Tags: truffle-migration, truffle-deployment

Here is my `A` contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

contract A {
    B public b;

    constructor() public {
        b = new B();
    }
}

contract B {}
```

As you can see, it is deploying an instance of `B` in its `constructor`. For me, both `A` & `B` are important, so I want to verify them both on *etherscan*.

But while using `truffle-plugin-verify`, I am getting this error:

```
pam@g3:~/verify$ truffle run verify A B --network kovan --license MIT
Verifying A
Pass - Verified: https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0xaf589F7A115b14C3825937bBd8A59203c84BE9c5#contracts
Verifying B
No instance of contract B found for network id 42
Failed to verify 1 contract(s): B
```

How can I verify the contract `B` here?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to specify the address of `B` separately. So in this case you have to manually figure out what address `B` was deployed to and run:

```
truffle run verify B@<address> --network kovan
```

If `B` was deployed from a contract and it has constructor arguments, you'd also need to manually retrieve those arguments (e.g. through [Tenderly](https://tenderly.co/)) and provide the ABI-encoded args with `--forceConstructorArgs string:<constructorArgs>`.